# UIImage is somehow adding padding for me

Tags: ios

I have an PNG image file foo@2x.png that is 128x128 pixels. My expectation is that when I load it on a retina device the resulting size will be 64x64 points. In fact though I am getting a UIImage* that is 100x100 pts, where the extra points (18pts on each side) are just empty (I confirmed by drawing a border in the containing UIImageView*).

I have tried loading the image via [UIImage imageNamed], [UIImage imageWithData], and [UIImage imageWithData:scale]. They all give back the same image, and I'm confused. Anyone able to explain where this extra space is coming from?

[EDIT] Per John's request,

[image]

[UPDATE] It seems this had to do with the simulator caching something from somewhere. Deleting the app from the simulator, doing a clean build, and re-running gives me the size expected. Not clear how this happened, since this isn't a changed or modified image file -- it's totally new and has never existed at 100x100 pts. Open to hearing how this could happen, but don't want to waste anyone's time chasing rabbits.

Comment: can you share with us the image you are using?

Comment: do you try to set image view's frame to needed?

Comment: Do you call the image as foo@2x.png or foo.png?

Comment: @СергейМалетин: The UImageView's frame is precisely that of the image, as expected and desired.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato: See the edit/link above. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @RauruFerro: As I said, I have tried loading the image with a few different ways, all of them coming back the same. If I use [UIImage imageNamed] then I use simply `@"foo"` and let iOS do the rest.

Comment: Assuming this isn't an issue with the image, the only way we can assist is if you show us more code. how you create the UIImageView, and how it gets put on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (see last UPDATE), somewhat bewildered but willing to move on with a healthy suspicion of what the simulator is doing.